# SPSS GLM Significance of Predictors are different when building interaction terms vs creating the interaction variables

Tags: spss, glm

I was wondering if anyone knows how SPSS builds the interaction terms/calculates the significance for predictors behind the scenes in a GLM? From my understanding it dummy codes variables and treats the one that comes alphabetically last as the reference group.

The reason I'm asking is I have a GLM model which has 3 continuous predictors and two categorical predictors (dummy coded). When I build all the 2-way and 3-way interactions with syntax ie:

Age_Centred Age_Centred*Dx  Age_Centred*gender  Age_Centred*Dx*gender BMI_Centred  BMI_Centred*Dx  BMI_Centred*gender  BMI_Centred*Dx*gender BPS_Centred BPS_Centred*Dx  BPS_Centred*gender BPS_Centred*Dx*gender  Dx  Dx*gender  Dx*ICV_Centred  Dx*ICV_Centred*gender  gender  ICV_Centred  ICV_Centred*gender.

vs manually creating all the variables by hand ie:

Age_Centred Age_Centred_Dx  Age_Centred_gender Age_Centred_gender_Dx BMI_Centred BMI_Centred_Dx  BMI_Centred_gender  BMI_Centred_gender_Dx BPS_Centred BPS_Centred_Dx  BPS_Centred_gender BPS_Centred_gender_Dx Dx  gender_Dx  ICV_Dx  ICV_Centred_Dx_gender  gender  ICV_Centred  ICV_gender.

I end up with a model which has the same intercept, overall significance, and R squared however the individual significance of the predictors changes. Refer to output below. To troubleshoot I've tried to flip the references groups when manually creating the variables but it still does not replicate the results. I've had another statistician try the same thing and ended up reaching the same point as what I did. Does it have to do with some of the parameters being redundant?

[Building the terms via syntax:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lySnw.png)

[Physically creating the variables by multiplying them together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyEK1.png)

Answer (score 0):

All the details one might reasonably want about how GLM (and UNIANOVA, which is the same underlying code) parameterizes models, estimates parameters, and conducts hypothesis tests are available in the *IBM SPSS Statistics Algorithms* manual, available for download as a pdf at ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/26.0/en/client/Manuals/IBM_SPSS_Statistics_Algorithms.pdf. (Note that this is a large file, about 78 MB; clicking on the link starts a download.) In addition to the information in the GLM chapter, appendices F (Indicator Method) and H (Sums of Squares) are relevant, respectively, for building the design matrix and specifying linear combinations of model parameters for computing sums of squares for testing hypotheses.

In building the design matrix, categorical predictors (factors) are indeed represented by sets of indicator (0-1) variables. For a factor with *k* levels, *k* indicator variables are created, one for each observed level of the factor. The procedure does not explicitly treat the last category (sorted in ascending order, alphabetical for strings) as a reference category, though in simpler models the effect of what's done is essentially the same. If there is an intercept in the model, then the *k<sup>th</sup>* indicator will be redundant (linearly dependent) on the intercept and the preceding *k-1* indicators. The estimation algorithm used in GLM/UNIANOVA will set the row and column in the cross-product matrix representing the redundant column in the design matrix to 0s, alias the corresponding parameter estimate to 0, and the results are similar to a reparameterization approach treating the last category as a reference category, except that you have to remember that it's there if you want to specify a linear combination of the parameters to estimate.

If you suppress the intercept, then for the first factor entered into the model the *k<sup>th</sup>* indicator would not be redundant (unless the factor is preceded by an unusual covariate or set of covariates). Any subsequent factors included in the model would involve redundant parameters, as would any interactions among factors, whether or not an intercept is included. Interactions among factors are created by multiplying the 0s and 1s for each level of the factors by those for each level of the other factor. So for an interaction of two two-level factors, there are four columns generated, of which typically the last three are redundant.

Covariates are entered simply by copying the values of the variables into the design matrix. Interactions involving covariates and other covariates multiply values for the columns involved within each row, and interactions involving covariates and factors multiply covariates (or products of them) by the indicator variables for the factor(s). Usually covariate-by-covariate terms do not involve redundancies, but factor-by-covariate terms do.

---

To get to the specifics of what's going on with your data, I can't replicate your exact results without your data, but I am able to replicate the patterns shown if I assume you've used the binary Dx variable as a covariate and the binary gender variable as a factor in each analysis. (There seem to actually be four continuous predictors in your model rather than three, but that doesn't affect anything of importance for understanding what's going on.)

There are two aspects of the situation to be considered. One is the parameterization and how the two ways of entering the variables into the model treat the variables and whether or not they produce the same estimates of parameters. The second is how the model specification results in the Type III tests shown in the ANOVA tables.

If I'm understanding things correctly based on what you've posted here, you should find if you compare parameter estimates for the two analyses that the parameter estimates for the intercepts and the non-redundant estimates for gender ([gender=0]) are the same, and have the same standard errors. For the terms involving just covariates or products of covariates, I expect that you will find the parameter estimates to differ between the two analyses and produce different t statistics. For interactions involving gender and covariates (which is all the other variables or products created outside the procedure), I expect the estimates will be the same in magnitude and opposite in sign, with the same standard errors.

None of the estimates or tests here are wrong. The models fitted involve interaction effects. An interaction means that effect of one variable varies by the levels of the other variable(s) in the interaction, and in order to estimate the same simple effects you have to parameterize the model in the same way, at least as far as the non-redundant parameters are concerned. However, to get the Type III tests for all terms to be identical, it's not always enough to have the same parameter estimates and standard errors. Type III tests involve a concept called containment that must also be considered.

For two effects in a model, effect A is contained in effect B if:

- A and B contain the same covariate terms, if any.
- B contains all factor effects in A, and at least one more (with the intercept   being contained in all factor-only effects).

In your original model, the intercept is included in the gender effect, gender is not included in any effects, and all the covariate main effects and two-way interactions among covariates are contained within the interactions between those terms and gender, while the three-way interactions (which include gender) are not contained within any other effects.

Type III sums of squares (not invented by SPSS, but by our friends at SAS) are based on linear combinations of parameters where a given effect is adjusted for any effects that do not contain it, and made orthogonal to any effects that contain it. The practical application of these rules is complicated (see Appendix H of the algorithms).

If you recode the gender variable to swap the 0 and 1 values, specify it as a covariate along with all the other variables, and fit the same model, you should be able to match all the non-redundant parameter estimates from the original model, along with their standard errors and t statistics. However, because the containment relationships in the original model are no longer there, the Type III tests for the terms not involving gender (which were previously contained in terms involving gender) will not match up.

The bottom line is that all results are translatable and all correct for what's being done, and that in order to make much sense out of individual terms you have to carefully focus on what's being estimated in a given parameterization, as well as the containment relationships. The difficult part gets simpler when you take seriously the fact that when variable X is involved in interaction terms, there is no single estimate of the effect of X. Any estimates are conditional one where you fix the value(s) of the terms with which X interacts.